# Calendar Items not showing after creation

Tags: calendar

I created a shared calendar in SP 2013 with 4 different views. When I create an event, it does not appear in the default calendar view, although the item has been created as it is visible in the view "All Events".

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: any filter on the default view? could you please check it?

Comment: No, there is no filter applied to the default view...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the view is correct. Check filters on the list view.

Comment: There are no filters set currently... I deleted my old calendar and created a new one without customizing anything, because I wanted to try if it worked at least there, but the same problem occurs... events are created but not displayed

Comment: I just changed the calendar in the list settings to "use this calendar to share member's schedule=no" and afterwards all the events were displayed. So the reason must be that those items aren't visible in shared mode... How can I accomplish to make them visible in shared mode?

Comment: Remove default view, add new and check items.